# What word/term describes someone in the following scenario?

Tags: word-request

So the scenario would be such as this:

William is in a hurry to get his medicine from a pharmacy in Walmart, which is about to close. Worried that the pharmacy would close before he gets there, he parks in the disabled parking spot. A stranger watches him do that and tells him

> Stranger: "You can't park there, man, it is for disabled parking only.
>
> William: I know, but it won't take more than a minute and I am in a hurry.
>
> Stranger: No, you gotta take your car off from the disabled parking
>   spot"
>
> William: "You are a cop? Or you are a vigilante or who are you to tell me
>   not to park there and not understand my urgency here?"

So my question here. If William wants to negatively describe him with a word, what would he say?

Comment: Would you explain a bit more why "social justice warrior" and "stickler for the rules" aren't suitable? It seems like you don't want vigilante because it has the idea of punishment - the more important part of the meaning of vigilante in my opinion is "outside the law" though. It would help also to know if you want something that is negative or positive.

Comment: @ColleenV It is negative. Someone who takes an issue if you park in the disabled parking not because of the law but because of his sense of fairness. So what word would describe a vigilante but doesn't punish?

Comment: So you want a negative word because it isn't that person's place to lecture you on what you're doing, even though what they are talking about is the right thing to do?

Comment: Is this [woman criticizing a dad at the store for using food stamps](https://youtu.be/C5mnu7c7yBQ) an example, or is it not right because she's just being rude and not telling him the right thing to do?

Comment: Yeah, close to that. Like I said if you park in the disabled parking for maybe just one minute, but someone takes a great issue with it. Funny video though!

Comment: @P.E.Dant In a hypothetical and very likely situation, there are numerous of disabled parking spots that are vacant and close to the entrance, and so if one person who is in a hurry and whose needs can be met rather quickly, such a circumstance, I think, even a disabled person would permit. So in that situation, if a third person comes and takes an issue with what that person did, I think he meets the definition of a jerk.

Comment: Lol, and in the dictionary, there is something called "extenuating circumstances" and it does exist in the judiciary system, you might want to take a look at that and realize not everything should be according to principle regardless of the specifics of a circumstance. So I bet in my hypothetical situation, even a disabled person would permit it, but it looks like you, on the other hand, doesn't really care.

Comment: I think the grouping together of "socially unjust" and "legally prohibited" into a single term doesn't really work. They're two very different concepts.

Comment: The first word I thought of: self-righteous. Maybe self-righteous 'paparazzi'?

Comment: In the Hebrew Bible he's called נָבִיא, traditionally translated "prophet".

Comment: @StoneyB Yeah, I incorrectly phrased the question. I should have phrased it in a way that would yield an answer such as "someone who applies his moral principles to every situation regardless of the specifics of a circumstance would be called a narrow-minded, sanctimonious, pious person. I blame my English skills for not yielding the answers close to what is in my mind.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom Then you need to put that in your question (there's an 'edit' link beneath it) rather than in the comments.

Comment: @StoneyB It doesn't feel like it is worth undertaking. Some community members here seem to take questions a bit personally and incorporate their morality to their answers.

Comment: There's an expression with *nanny* that I can't think of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What word/term describes someone in the following scenario?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98326/what-word-term-describes-someone-in-the-following-scenario)

Comment: @P.E.Dant: I believe this inconsistency, such as it is, is fundamental to the question. (Also, there is nothing specifically preventing "adherence to law" as a moral principle, one of those being foisted on others. Quite the contrary.)

Comment: Is *legalist* the word you're looking for?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Maybe so, but that was inherent in the first version of the question. (And, of course, while e.g. speed limits are democratically determined, some people stick to them rigidly, and even tell others to do the same, while some go a bit over, and some go a lot faster. You can't ignore that kind of difference in favor of basic theory about how laws are decided: there is a real distinction between practical worldviews of *obeying* those laws.)

Comment: I now gleefully visualize Alrestom standing in a parking lot, after having been well and truly rogered for parking in a handicapped spot, sputtering at the good citizen who called him out: "Why, you ... you are nothing but a ... a rhadamantine moralist!"

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom Your question is good one & it unearthed some valuable words. What I think you don't understand is that here, instead of the Gasht-e Ershad, we have citizens. You don't have to be a "cop" or a "vigilante" to do the work of a citizen. You just have to be "regular folks" like the guy who told "William" that his "urgency" is less important than respect for the law. No, he was not a cop, nor a vigilante, and he doesn't want or need to be. He's a plain old standard-issue American, and good on him. It's not _him_ telling you (sorry, telling "William") not to park there. It's _us_.

Comment: I argue that a reasonable person/law/whoever should warrant exceptions of the law under urgent or demanding circumstances. A reasonable person would say that in William’s situation, the benefits way outweigh the possible harm that might occur because of Williams’ illegal action. Now you might say, if we allow William, then everybody else would do. But that’s not really right. There is only one person at that moment who is in a hurry to get his medicine.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom - And that person is the most important person in all the world, isn't he?

Comment: Fwiw i believe that if William's needs are so urgent that finding a proper parking spot is out of the question, then maybe he can't afford discussing the matter with a random stranger.

Comment: @YoungFrog Those kinds of exchanges occur while ur getting out of the car and walking to the pharmacy.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment: **"...someone who applies his moral principles to every situation regardless of the specifics of a circumstance would be called a narrow-minded, sanctimonious, pious person."** I think this might help:

> **[Rhad·a·man·thine](https://www.google.com.hk/?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=rhadamanthine+definition)**
>
> /ˌradəˈmanθʌɪn/
>
> adjective, literary
>
> showing stern and **inflexible judgement**.

'Rhadamanthine moralists'

Comment: That is a very interesting word. How did you come across such a word?

Comment: -1 because this answer is, literally, *not useful*. Even if the OP did choose to use that word, 99.9999999% of his/her audience would not know what it meant.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I am familiar with the word. I disagree that just because a word doesn't come up regularly in casual conversation that it's not worth knowing about. Rhadamanthine and Rhadamant are really great words to have in your pocket when you need them.

Comment: @Alan, A bread in hand is better than none. It does (at least) fit the description provided. I respect your opinion though.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, Quoting the OP's comment "**I incorrectly phrased the question**. I **should have phrased** it in a way that would yield an answer such as **"someone who applies his moral principles to every situation regardless of the specifics of a circumstance would be called a narrow-minded, sanctimonious, pious person.** I blame my English skills for not yielding the answers close to what is in my mind."

Comment: Rememer @shin I am downvoting the word, not you. The *Oxford English Dictionary* classifies *Rhadamanthine* as Frequency Band 2: "Band 2 contains words which occur **fewer than 0.01 times per million words in typical modern English usage.** These **are almost exclusively terms which are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most people.** Many are technical terms from specialized discourses. Examples taken from the most frequently attested part of the band include *decanate*, *ennead* and *scintillometer* (nouns)..." How useful, other than showing off one's vocabulary, is that?

Comment: I know, @Alan. I do understand your point. I added the word for reference, regardless of its statistical usage. One common word in contemporary times may become profound and rarely used after some years, and vice versa. Language is continuously evolving after all.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: If the most applicable word/phrase for a given request is a highly unusual one, that in itself is useful information for any learner -- showing that English doesn't really support the concept well -- although this answer could stand to call out the rarity of the word more clearly.

Comment: @shin Don't you mean "Half a bird is better than none?"

Comment: @P.E. it's more like a wisp of a feather in the hand, given that it makes up less than, "oops," fewer than .01 per million parts of the bird.

Comment: @AlanCarmack That is clearly changing to a horse of another color in midstream.

Answer (score 2):

If I answer the question as stated (Version 3), then I agree that *legalist* is a good choice, and in the context you provide, it would be used in a negative way. This refers specifically to William's taking umbrage at the stranger's insistence on the letter of the law. Another term would be *stickler for the law*, although this *stickler for the rules* was specifically ruled out in the now obsolete Version 1 of the question. Closely associated with *legalist* or *legalistic* is *pedant*, which crops up in the case of grammar nazis, but which can generally apply to

> A person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules

([Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pedant))

Taking a broader view, William can call the stranger just about any  word in the book of negative words, although I think *asshole* particularly fits the overall situation, since the stranger is

> An irritating or contemptible person.

You could also guy the stranger *meddlesome*

> Fond of meddling; interfering

with *to meddle* meaning

> Interfere in or busy oneself unduly with something that is not one’s concern

To William, it is not really the stranger's concern.

*Interfering, pedantic, legalistic asshole* would work. That is more than one word, but then again *word* can mean "a brief remark" ([link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/word) to *Merriam-Webster* dictionary)

Comment: Let's be certain that Mr. Alrestom understands that his use of the suggested term of opprobrium is likely to result not in the conflict's resolution, but to its expansion beyond the merely verbal into a much less ephemeral and more immediately active realm.

Answer (score 1):

*Legalist* seems to fit well as an adherent of *legalism* which is:

> strict adherence, or the principle of strict adherence, to law or
>   prescription, especially to the letter rather than the spirit.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/legalist

Comment: Does _legalist_ describe  someone who might "reprimand or tell the other not to do anything that is socially unjust?"

Comment: @P.E Dant Not sure that it does. As others have noted I'm not sure what to picture or how to fit that into a single concept. I think this encompasses most of the question though.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Dad"?

What are you my Dad? Go mind your own [expletive] business.

Some other gems from the thesaurus:

Meddler, Busybody

(my favorites)

Buttinsky, Sidewalk superintendent

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Hall monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_monitor) from the volunteer, usually a student, who would patrol the halls during class times, hunting for students who might be trying to skip class.

```
A: "You can't park there!"
B: "What are you, the hall monitor? Get lost!"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent borrowing from German: [Blockwart](https://munchkinwrangler.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/blockwart-of-the-decade/). It perfectly describes the sort of self-righteous legalistic busybody, and the link in fact describes a fellow in Germany doing exactly as you describe.

See the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockleiter for the origin in Nazi party organization.